# Different view depending on which state

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular page which has a login page, a register account page, and the rest of the page. Login/register looks different from the other pages, as they have no sidebar, toolbar, and so on. Totally different layout. I have an index page and an index controller, which determines which view to load currently. Something like this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="IndexController as vm">
    <div ui-view ng-if="$state.current.name === 'home'"></div>
    <div ng-if="$state.current.name !== 'home'">
        <!--TOOLBAR-->
        <!--SIDEBAR-->
        <div ui-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So basically if the current state is `home`, it should load the first view (with no toolbar, sidenav etc.). If the current state is not set to `home`, it should show the toolbar, sidebar, and so on. I thought this would work, but is there a better way to do it? I have all my states inside my `app.js`.

Let me know if there's a better way of separating the different views. Why I'm doing this, is because I want to keep all the includes (models, views, controllers) and other scripts on one page (my index.html which contains the above) and just change the view accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `controller as` syntax, i'm assuming `$state` isn't defined. You should add it to the controller scope (not $scope) (`this.$state = $state`) and call it using `vm.$state.current...`.

Ideally you wouldn't do this though and use `ui-router`s nested states which solves this problem exactly.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views

There are a number of ways to do this. One is to fork the states so home does not inherit parent views.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {})
.state('app', {}) // has parent views like menu
.state('app.foo', {}) // inherits views from app
```

Or used **named views**

```
<body>
  <div ui-view="menu"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>

$stateProvider.state('app' { views: { menu: { ... } } } )
.state('app.home', { views: { 'menu@app': { /* inject empty tpl */ }, 'content@app' : { ... }  } )
.state('app.foo', { views: { 'content@app' : { ... } } } );
```

Comment: So I would simply do something like: Home has signin and signup. `home.signin` and `home.signup` as states. Then simply do what I did before, where I check if the state is set to `home` or not?

Comment: Do what you can not to have your templates check the state. The templates should be as decoupled from the states as possible. Do that logic in the state provider.

Comment: How would I make my view/template then? Different structures (as you can see).

Comment: I would use the named views approach

Comment: That didn't really work for me. It still loaded the template and then it got hidden away.